# Can't figure it out: Have eclipse use single window

Tags: eclipse

I haven't used eclipse in a while, and in opening it today somehow something is set so that all windows float separately.  I want them all docked in the same instance/whatever.  I haven't used the magic word to google or eclipse help figure out how to get things all back under the same roof, and assume it is something ditzy I am just missing - this is version 23.0.2.1259578 - adtproduct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried going to the Menu Bar : Window -> Reset Perspective ?

Mac : [image: Reset Perspective Location]

Windows : http://youtu.be/1onYF0HCMBw?t=27s

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad you got it sussed =)